# Uncaught ReferenceError on jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to run this script

```
window.onpopstate = function(popEvent) {
    let urlPath = window.location.pathName;
    let slash = page.lastIndexOf("/");
    let page = urlPath.substr(slash+1);
    let $tab;

    if (page = '') {
        $tab = $("#tabs .tab:first-of-type");
        page = $tab.attr("href");
    }

    else { $tab = $("#tabs .tab[href="+CSS.escape(page)+"]") }

    $tab.addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");

    $.ajax({url: "subpages/"+page, function(html) {
        $(".append").html(html);
    } });
}
```

I’m getting the error message:

> foo.js:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'page' before initialization at window.onpopstate (foo.js:38:15)

I don’t really get what’s the problem.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: You call `page.lastIndexOf()`, yet you haven't defined `page` anywhere - at least nowhere in scope of this function.

Comment: `let slash = page.lastIndexOf("/"); <--HMMM-->  let page = urlPath.substr(slash+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused only by mistyping: `page` → `urlPath`

```
window.onpopstate = function(popEvent) {
    let urlPath = window.location.pathName;
    let slash = urlPath.lastIndexOf("/");  // HERE
    let page = urlPath.substr(slash+1);
    let $tab;

    if (page = '') {
        $tab = $("#tabs .tab:first-of-type");
        page = $tab.attr("href");
    }

    else { $tab = $("#tabs .tab[href="+CSS.escape(page)+"]") }

    $tab.addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");

    $.ajax({url: "subpages/"+page, function(html) {
        $(".append").html(html);
    } });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I change that I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: urlPath is undefined`.

Comment: All right, it looks like `.pathname` in line 2 is case-sensitive and should be written all lowercase. Now, at least the first part of the script seems to work, while the part `{ $tab = $("#tabs .tab[href="+CSS.escape(page)+"]") }` gives out the error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tabs .tab[href=]` now. Any idea why?